# Oracle PL/SQL how to find this syntax error?

Tags: oracle, plsql

In the Oracle PL/SQL , I have this coding, it gives me complier error. I don't know why, looks like I have everything ...

Please help.

Thanks

```
 ORA-06550: line 6, column 5:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "CREATE" when expecting one of the following:

   ( begin case declare end exit for goto if loop mod null
   pragma raise return select update while with <an identifier>
   <a double-quoted delimited-identifier> <a bind variable> <<
   continue close current delete fetch lock insert open rollback
   savepoint set sql execute commit forall merge pipe purge
06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
*Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
*Action:
```

Code is

```
begin
  for c in (select id from tmp_A)
  loop
    dbms_output.put_line(c.id);

    create table tmp_c as 
    select B.name from tmp_B B where B.id = c.id;   

    drop table tmp_c;
  end loop;
end;
/
```

Comment: Why do you want to create a table at runtime?  It is exceedingly rare in Oracle for that to be necessary and the vast majority of times that people write code like this, it is an error.

Comment: I have a complex correlated subquery, I want to divide it into easy-to-understand small pieces .

Comment: That doesn't seem like a sensible reason to create tables at runtime.  Resorting to dynamic SQL is not going to make your code easier to understand.  It will prevent multiple sessions from calling the same code successfully (tables you create dynamcially are visible immediately to all sessions).  Potentially, you may want  to create a single global temporary table outside of your procedure and then insert into that temporary table in your code but even that is pretty unusual.  If you want to divide code into easier to understand pieces, use modular functions and procedures.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you cannot call ddl statments (CREATE, DROP, ALTER, etc) in PL/SQL directly.
You can, however use an execute immediate statement:

```
begin
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'CREATE TABLE MYTABLE(DT DATE)';
end;
```

See:

```
http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/PL/SQL_FAQ#Can_one_call_DDL_statements_from_PL.2FSQL.3F
```

Comment: @user595234 - Because you should not be creating objects dynamically.  If there were use cases where it made sense to create objects as part of normal code paths, Oracle might invest the time to make that easier rather than forcing you to use dynamic SQL every time you reference the dynamic object.  Since there really aren't such use cases, however, it's not worth the added complexity to make it particularly easy.

Comment: Here's one answer: http://www.toadworld.com/Blogs/tabid/67/EntryId/549/Why-cant-I-execute-DDL-natively-in-PL-SQL.aspx